# Minor issues in program

Tags: c

I'm creating a program to find the individual and total kilowatt hours used and charge, and customer total.
The error messages I'm getting are `undefined reference to "If"` and `Id returned 1 exit status`
What's causing this?

```
 /* program to determine cost for a certain number of kilowatt hours */

#include <stdio.h> /* printf, scanf definitions */
#include <math.h>

double charges_to_return(int kwh_f);

int main (void)
{
    int cust_number;
    int kwh;
    int total_cust;
    int total_kwh;
    double total_charge;
    double cust_charge;
    double charge;

    total_cust = 0;
    total_kwh = 0;
    total_charge = 0;
    cust_number = 0;

    while (cust_number != -1)
    {   
        printf("Enter customer number and kwh (-1 to quit): ");
        scanf("%d %d", &cust_number, &kwh);

        If (cust_number != -1);
        {
            total_cust++;
            total_kwh = total_kwh + kwh;
            cust_charge = charges_to_return(kwh);
            total_charge = total_charge + cust_charge;

            printf("Customer Num: %d     KWH used: %d    Charge: %.2lf", cust_number, kwh, cust_charge);
        }
    }

    printf("Total Customers:  %d     Total KWH used:  %d        Total Charges:  %.2f", total_cust, total_kwh, total_charge);

    return (0);     
}
```

Comment: C is case sensitive. You have If, not if

Comment: that looks very homework-like..

Comment: `If (cust_number != -1);` --> `if (cust_number != -1)` note ';'

Comment: Also, compile with terse warnings emabled, something like `gcc -Wall -pedantic-errors -o foo foo.c`, else you won't see some useful warnings. And until you are a beginner (and seemingly don't have an idea as to what you are doing), always fix all warnings before running your progam, or there be dragons.

Comment: specific code debugging question

Comment: Not checking the return value of scanf() is a recipe for disaster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't tried googling the error message, have you... this is a linker error telling you that there's no function defined with the name `If`. Maybe you wanted to write a branch statement with the `if` keyword instead... C is case sensitive.

Sidenote: after you fixed this, remove the semi-colon from after the `if`, because that's an empty statement. Then, indent and format your code because it's an unreadable utter mess currently. You don't only have minor problems with your code, you have **major** problems with the basics.

Comment: What happened to the "too specific" reason for closing stuff?

Comment: @xaxxon Too localized, you mean? That's gone :( Do a search on Meta for details.